# Show that $xy=0$ is a variety but not a manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds

As a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ the equation $xy=0$ is the union of $x=0$ and $y=0$.  That is two lines. This is an algebraic variety. Why is this not a manifold?

Comment: A heuristic way to think about this is that every manifold of dimension $n$ has a tangent space of dim $n$ at every point. Now ask, what is the tangent space at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At all points other than that intersection, this variety is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. If it is a manifold, it should therefore by locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ at every point. At the intersection, deletion of a single point splits the neighborhood into four connected components. But deletion of a point in $\mathbb R$ splits the neighborhood of that point into only two connected components. So they are not locally homeomorphic.